# Cookie will not set for keep me logged in. PHP

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

Attempting to add a "keep me logged in". Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, but on the initial login when "keep me logged in" is checked, this will run:

```
$email_and_password = array($email_from_html, $pass_from_html);
setcookie("StayLoggedZod", $email_and_password, time()+3600*24*30);
```

$email_from_html & $pass_from_html are the user's email and password being stored into an array and that being stored into a cookie.

Now when you go back to the site after leaving, the initial page does this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['StayLoggedZod'])) 
{
$email_and_password = $_COOKIE['StayLoggedZod'];
$stored_email = $email_and_password[0];
$stored_password = $email_and_password[1];
//USES THE E-MAIL AND PASS STORED IN HERE TO LOG INTO WEBSITE VIA MySQL DB, I EXCLUDED THIS CODE BECAUSE I KNOW THIS PART WORKS.
}
else
{
header("location:login.php");
}
```

It returns no errors, I couldn't get it to work so I made a quick test page like this:

```
$cookie_data = $_COOKIE['StayLoggedZod'];
$the_email = $cookie_data[0];
$the_pass = $cookie_data[1];
$display_string = "This is my email".$the_email.". This is my password".$the_pass;
echo $display_string;
```

No data shows up aside from "This is my email" ect.

This is my first time making a keep my logged in, not sure what I'm missing, hope I was thorough with my explanation.
-Mike

Comment: Please don't tell me you are storing the password in the cookie.

Comment: Not when I make it live, I was just trying to get this to work before changing alot of stuff around, I'll have a unique ID generated instead of the password and have that stored in the DB and use that as the reference instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you should not store sensitive details like the password in a cookie. Cookies are stored on the client side and are editable and visible

2) check the man page for setcookie http://php.net/setcookie

you will see that the second parameter (the value that you want to store) should be a string (so if you want to store arrays think of a method to store them as a string like serialization or json encoding)

Comment: I'm absolutely going to change storing the password and use a generated unique ID stored in the cookie and the DB and reference that instead of the password, I was just trying to get this to work before I changed alot of stuff around. I had no clue it had to be a string, going to encode it differently now. Thank you!

Comment: @user1053263 ok, I am glad it helps. But I guess that usually the user authentication is handled via sessions and the system automatically stores the session id (in a cookie being the most common option) and from what you say it seems like you want to replicate this system

Comment: I have sessions working on the server side, it's just once you leave the browser, the sessions are destroyed and my friends became annoyed with it, it's why I'm adding this in.

Comment: I think that can be fixed if you set a value for the `session.cookie_lifetime` setting in your php.ini

Comment: @user1053263 take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Comment: ohh... so I can set my session to a month or until they log out?

Comment: yes, right. Just give it a big enough value and also check the value for `session.gc_maxlifetime` that's the session lifetime (number of seconds after which the garbage collector is ran). And the garbage collector deletes data depending on the relation between `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_probability`

Comment: Holy crap, that worked perfect. I gave it a value of 9999 for both life time and max life time... does that work by seconds?

Comment: :) yes, seconds.. read that man page, all the values I mentioned above have a significant role in your session lifetime

Comment: You're the freaken man, this saved me alot of frustration. You deserve the answer for this... Why in gods name would anyone want to use cookies for keep me logged in in the first place? Every tutorial uses cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setcookie("StayLoggedZod", serialize($email_and_password), time()+3600*24*30);
```

and invoke:

```
$email_and_password = unserialize($_COOKIE['StayLoggedZod']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of persistent login cookies is: do **not** store passwords in a cookie!

Instead, generate a cookie with the username and a random token (from a suitably large space), store this random token inside the user table.

When the cookie is presented, the username and token combination is looked up:

- if the combination matches, the user is signed in; a new token is generated and saved, the cookie is updated
- if the combination does not match, the cookie is ignored

When a user session has started as a result of a "remember me" cookie, you should prompt for password when they access sensitive information (such as personally identifiable data).

There's an improvement to this process that handles compromised cookies, outlined [here](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice).