# Keep a user logged in with cookies

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have this forum and I want to keep users logged in if they check the check box that says logged it. So i added this php code to set the cookie :

```
$year = time() + 31536000;
    if($_POST['remember']) {
setcookie('email', $_SESSION['email'], $year);
}
elseif(!$_POST['remember']) {
if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) {
    $past = time() - 100;
    setcookie(email, gone, $past);
}
}
```

But, how do i keep them signed in into my forum using this cookie, I have been stuck on this for some time now.

Comment: This is a pretty unsafe method unless your site is always secure. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896020/cookie-will-not-set-for-keep-me-logged-in-php/10896259#10896259) should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this code on top of your login page

if(isset($_COOKIE["email"])){

$_SESSION['email']=$_COOKIE["email"];

header("location: some-page.php");

exit();

}

thats all

Answer (score 1):

For keep user signed every time your page loads you have to check weather your cookie is set if it is then you can redirect user to your internal pages and pass login page,for that you can set user id in encrypted form by which you can get user information.

Answer (score 1):

First check for the cookie that if cookie is set assign that variable to your session variable and do the rest of your code